# Split one row into 3 rows in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to create a new table based on a given table in SQL Server 2008 R2 on Win7.

Given table:

```
 id1  id2  valueA   valueB    valueC
 -----------------------------------
 dva  365  63213      3879      605
```

I need a table:

```
 id1  id2     valueA   valueB   valueC
 -------------------------------------
 dva  365_A   63213        0        0
 dva  365_B       0     3879        0
 dva  365_C       0        0      605
```

There are also other columns, but I need to keep them same for each new row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the table structure fixed or do you have more columns?

Comment: Column data types? Is the result row order important?

Comment: id1, id2 are sting, others are float.

Comment: Did you attempt any TSQL for this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id1, CONCAT(id2, '_A'), valueA, 0 AS valueB, 0 AS valueC
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT id1, CONCAT(id2, '_B'), 0, valueB, 0
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT id1, CONCAT(id2, '_C'), 0, 0, valueC
FROM mytable
```

Depending on the date type of `id2` you may need to cast this field inside `CONCAT`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2985a/2)

Answer (score 2):

If the structure is really fixed as you told in comments, this will work fine.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    id1 VARCHAR(10)
    , id2 VARCHAR(10)
    , valueA FLOAT
    , valueB FLOAT
    , valueC FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO @Test (id1, id2, valueA, valueB, valueC)
VALUES ('dva', 365, 63213, 3879, 605);

SELECT id1
    , CASE TT.RowNo
        WHEN 1 THEN id2 + '_A'
        WHEN 2 THEN id2 + '_B'
        WHEN 3 THEN id2 + '_C'
    END AS id2
    , CASE TT.RowNo
        WHEN 1 THEN valueA
        ELSE 0
    END AS valueA
    , CASE TT.RowNo
        WHEN 2 THEN valueB
        ELSE 0
    END AS valueB
    , CASE TT.RowNo
        WHEN 3 THEN valueC
        ELSE 0
    END AS valueC
FROM @Test AS T
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS TT(RowNo);
```

`CROSS JOIN` will multiply your row by 3 and then you can simply use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) statement to apply desired logic.

**Output:**

```
id1 id2     valueA  valueB  valueC
----------------------------------
dva 365_A   63213   0       0
dva 365_B   0       3879    0
dva 365_C   0       0       605
```